# Is there a way to allow a slackbot to post in any channel its called in

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

The slackbot is able to post in one channel, however I was wondering if there was a way to allow it to post in whatever channel its installed/called in.

```js
bot.on('start', () => {
   const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':cat:'
    };

    bot.postMessageToChannel('general','It is a bot.', params);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through an array of channels?

```
const channelList = ['general', 'off-topic', 'new-channel'];
channelList.forEach(channel => bot.postMessageToChannel(channel, 'It is a bot.', params));
```

Comment: I wanted to post in one channel at a time, Just the channel that called it. So if 'general' called it, i want it just to post in general, if 'off-topic' called it, it would just post in off topic. Also if i create new channels and install the bot, to be able to post in the new channels as well.